# Awk / perl call command with input blocks

Tags: perl, awk

I have a script called `processor.sh` that processes stdin. It processes a block of lines, like this:

```
address: abc
phone: 123
user: def
```

Consider that I have the following file:

```
address: a1
phone: p1
user: u1

address: a2
phone: p2
user: u2

address: a3
phone: p3
user: u3
```

I'd like to call `processor.sh` multiple times, once per block, and provide it with the block of text as-is to its stdin.

I know it can be done by splitting into temporary files using something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76929/how-to-split-a-file-by-using-keyword-boundaries). I'm looking to avoid having to create temporary files, i.e. use pipes only.

Is there a short (i.e. something that can be reasonably called a one-liner) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
perl -MIPC::Run=run -00ne'run [ "processor.sh" ], "<", \$_'
```

Or if you want the trailing lines removed:

```sh
perl -MIPC::Run=run -00nle'run [ "processor.sh" ], "<", \"$_\n"'
```

Comment: Alternative without `IPC::Run`: `perl -00 -ne 'open my $fh, "|-", "processor.sh" or die $!; print $fh $_'`

Answer (score 3):

with `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= '{cmd="processor.sh"; 
               print | cmd; 
               close(cmd)}' file
```

one advantage is your records can be of varying length as long as there is at least one empty line separating them.